# Creating an extension method for a type that has a constructor, is a type constraint required?

Tags: scala

Say I have a type like:

```
case class Product(value: String)
```

I have a constructor for this case class that returns

```
Either(String, Option[Product])
```

Now I want to create an extension method that will basically mimic this behaviour for all types that have this same pattern.

```
val leftMessage = "leftMessage"
val product: Option[Product] = Some("sku123") match {
   case Some(sku) => Right(Product(sku))
   case None =>
     Left(rightMessage)
}
```

So when trying to make an extension method I tried this:

```
class SomeOps[T](either: Either[String, T]) {
   def toSomething(value: Option[String], leftMessage: String): Either[String, Option[T] = value match {
      case Some(v) => T.apply(v) match {
         case Right(r) => Some(r)
         case _ => Left(leftMessage)
      }
      case None => Right(None)
}
```

This doesn't work because I need to somehow put a constraint such that my type `T` has a constructor that takes a string I believe.

Is there a way to abstract over this behaviour using an extension method?

Comment: Use a **typeclass** instead.

Comment: The case class is in a library where I have no control over @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: So what? One of the main points of **typeclasses** is to be able to extend third-party types. Take a look to [this](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html) and [this](https://gist.github.com/BalmungSan/c19557030181c0dc36533f3de7d7abf4).

Answer (score 1):

Luis is right in the comments. You do  need a typeclass for this. By using a typeclass, you can generalize this "needs to have a constructor" then provide instances for whatever type you need. It's going to look like this:

```scala
case class Product(value: String)

trait FromString[T] {
  def parse(s: String, errorMessage: String): Either[String, T]
}

object fromStringInstances {
  implicit object ProductFromString extends FromString[Product] {
    def parse(s: String, errorMessage: String) = Right(Product(s))
  }
}

object extensions {
  implicit class SomeOps(val s: String) extends AnyVal {
    def parseString[T: FromString](errorMessage: String): Either[String, T] = {
      implicitly[FromString[T]].parse(s, errorMessage)
    }
  }
}

object Hello extends App {
  import extensions._
  import fromStringInstances._

  val p: Either[String, Product] = "123".parseString("Error")
}
```

PS: I removed the `Option` to make it easier to read, but adding it should not be a major problem